# compute a weighted sum with many variables

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with many `x` and `y` columns, but showing an example with 5 below

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(505)
df <- data.frame(
x1 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),
x2 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),
x3 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),  
x4 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE), 
x5 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),   
y1 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE), 
y2 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),
y3 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),  
y4 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),  
y5 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE))
```

My task can be achieved with the code below

```
df |> mutate(
  sum1 = x1 * as.numeric(x1 > -1 & y1 > -1) +
         x2 * as.numeric(x2 > -1 & y2 > -1) +
         x3 * as.numeric(x3 > -1 & y3 > -1) +
         x4 * as.numeric(x4 > -1 & y4 > -1) +
         x5 * as.numeric(x5 > -1 & y5 > -1)
```

Because I have 25 `x` and `y` variables, my question is: is there a better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xs <- paste0("x", 1:5)
ys <- paste0("y", 1:5)

rowSums(df[xs] * (df[xs] > -1 & df[ys] > -1))

# Alternatively
foo <- \(x, y) replace(x, pmin(x, y) <= -1, 0)
Reduce("+", Map(foo, df[xs], df[ys]))


# [1] 2 3 1 4 6 3 0 0 1 2
```

Comment: Much better than mine, a one-liner solves it. I still prefer my way of getting the columns' names, though.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R solution.
Get the columns whose names start with a `"x"` and the ones starting with a `"y"`. With `mapply` compute the new values for each pair of `"x"` and `"y"` and pipe to `rowSums` to get the wanted result. Put it all together and assign the new column its name `"sum1"`.

```r
set.seed(2024)
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  x2 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  x3 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),  
  x4 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE), 
  x5 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),   
  y1 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE), 
  y2 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  y3 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),  
  y4 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE),  
  y5 = sample(-2 : 4,size = 10, replace = TRUE))

xnames <- grep("x", names(df), value = TRUE)
ynames <- grep("y", names(df), value = TRUE)

df <- cbind(df,
      mapply(\(ix, iy, DF) {
        x <- DF[[ix]]
        y <- DF[[iy]]
        x*as.integer(x > -1 & y > -1)
      }, xnames, ynames, MoreArgs = list(DF = df)) |>
        rowSums()
)
names(df)[ncol(df)] <- "sum1"
df
#>    x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 sum1
#> 1  -1  4 -1  1  1 -2 -2 -2  3  3    2
#> 2   2  2 -1  1 -1 -1  3  0 -2  1    2
#> 3   2  0  2  1  1 -2  1  1 -2  3    3
#> 4   1  2 -2  0  1 -2 -2  2  2 -2    0
#> 5   4  3  0 -1  4 -2  4  3  0 -2    3
#> 6  -2  1  0  1  1  3  2  0  2  1    3
#> 7   2  3 -2  1 -2 -1  0 -2  1  3    4
#> 8  -2 -1  3  4  2 -2  2 -2  0  0    6
#> 9  -1 -1 -2  4  1  0 -1  0  1 -1    4
#> 10 -1  1  1 -2  0 -2 -1  0  2  0    1
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can try the code below

```
> lst <- split.default(df, sub("\\d+", "", names(df)))

> rowSums(lst$x * (do.call(pmin, lst) > -1))
 [1] 2 3 1 4 6 3 0 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are ways to handle this task in a better way.
Let me provide my solution as follows

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Assuming df is your dataframe and has 25 pairs of x and y columns
x_cols <- paste0("x", 1:25)
y_cols <- paste0("y", 1:25)

# Initialize sum1 column
df$sum1 <- 0

# Iterate over the pairs of columns
for(i in seq_along(x_cols)) {
  x_col_name <- x_cols[i]
  y_col_name <- y_cols[i]
  
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(sum1 = sum1 + ifelse(!!sym(x_col_name) > -1 & !!sym(y_col_name) > -1, !!sym(x_col_name), 0))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting an error: "! non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Comment: @papgeo the reason of the error is that the code is receiving a non-numeric argument.
I have updated the code, it should work now.